# Nuke Python - How to set values on XY_Knob individually?

Tags: python, coordinate, nuke

**Background**

I am building a pretty cool tool in Python. Somehow I have been able to figure out all of the difficult parts thus far on my own, but this part has me!

**Question**
Im trying to set the values `(x, y)` of an `XY_Knob` individually. Here are my issues:

if I type:

```
nuke.selectedNode()['pos1'].setValue(1205)
```

it will set both X and Y to 1205. If I type:

```
nuke.selectedNode()['pos1'].setValue(1205, 1740)
```

It does not give me an error, but simply prints `Result:` in the script editor, while changing nothing on the node.

Is it possible for anyone to add some insight?

Comment: I know nothing about NUKE python (this is actually the first I've heard of it), but have you tried help(nuke.selectedNode()['pos1].setvalue) ?

Comment: Nuke is a VFX program that has python within it. Not a specific language of python if thats what you were thinking, and yeah doesnt help me :( Thanks though!

Comment: Actually, i lied, that DID help me. I just couldnt get the help file to run, needed to restart the program. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it! You should update your question with the solution you found in case someone with the same problem finds this page in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - if anyone is wondering... the list of args is setValue(value, index, time, view) so to set x to 1250 and y to 650 it would go:

```
nuke.selectedNode()['pos1'].setValue(1250, 0)
nuke.selectedNode()['pos1'].setValue(650, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also enter the information in list form:

```
nuke.selectedNode()['pos1'].setValue([1205, 1740])
```